# What is the proper way to open a url from a scope in c++?

Tags: c++, scope, ubuntu-touch

What is the proper way to open a url from a Ubuntu-scope in c++?
(this is Ubuntu touch specific)

This is what I've tried (This function is called from the ActivationResponse.):

```
static void open_url(std::string const& uri) {
//    url_dispatch_send(uri.c_str(), NULL, NULL);
/*    
 *    I found this in the libertine-scope, but I wasn't able to import
 *    the right libraries
 */

//    Qt.openUrlExternally(uri.c_str());
/*    
 *    I found this at https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/phone/platform/guides/url-dispatcher-guide/ 
 *    and https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/phone/apps/qml/tutorials/register-your-app-url-dispatcher/
 *    but it is actually meant to be used in QML, so it isn't recognized.
 *    I hoped it would work by using QtQuick or QtQml
 */

//    QDesktopServices::openUrl(QUrl(QString(uri), QUrl::TolerantMode));
//    QDesktopServices::openUrl(QUrl("http://www.google.com", QUrl::TolerantMode));
/*    
 *    I found this at https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/phone/platform/guides/url-dispatcher-guide/ 
 *    and http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdesktopservices.html#openUrl
 *    this compiles, but the scope crashes on execution.
 *    
 */
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Open URL from C++ code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17347950/open-url-from-c-code)

Comment: It's about Ubuntu-scopes (in Qt) ...