# How to open an URL in an existing browser window using C++ on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, browser, shellexecute

At the moment I'm using:

```
String Url = L"http://dr.dk";
ShellExecuteW(0, L"open", Url.c_str(), NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWDEFAULT);
```

This gives me a new tab in the default browser.

I would like **NOT** to get at new tab, but instead replace the content 
of the active tab in the browser, to simulate that it was a browser 
bookmark that was clicked.

Any Idea how to do this ?

Thanks in advance
Best regards
Asger

Comment: You could refer to this forum post.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17347950/open-url-from-c-code