# How to add link to imGui button?

Tags: c++, imgui

I want to create an ImGui button, when I click on this button, I want it to redirect to a url, that is, to the browser, how can I do that? can you help me please?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I open a URL from C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17347950/how-do-i-open-a-url-from-c)

Answer (score 2):

Creating a button:

```
    #[imgui( 
        button(size = "button_size", 
        label = "Click me!", 
        catch ="click"),
        separator,
        display(label = "Clicks"),
    )] 
    count: i32, } 
const fn button_size() -> (f32, f32){ 
(100.0, 20.0)
}
```

However, opening a webpage is a bit harder   since it depends on the api of the os that you're using. Doing that for windows and mac would look like this:

```
void OsOpenInShell(const char* path) { 
#ifdef _WIN32 
    // Note: executable path must use  backslashes! 
    ::ShellExecuteA(NULL, "open", path, NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWDEFAULT); 
#else 
#if __APPLE__ const char* open_executable = "open"; 
#else 
    const char* open_executable = "xdg 
    open"; 
#endif char command[256]; 
    snprintf(command, 256, "%s \"%s\"", 
    open_executable, path); 
    system(command); 
#endif
```

Then you could put the previous code inside this:

```
let events = ui.imgui_ext(&mut buttons); 
if events.click { 
 *insert code*
 }
```

Comment: Does code for creating button and receiving click event need to be so complex? Won't `if (ImGui::Button("SampleText")) { /*execute url logic here*/ }` do enough job as example? Just asking coz I've never seen such complex implementation for button.

Comment: no, it doesn't have to be that long but this is an example with some attributes

Comment: sure. I think it's good to omit not needed code when trying to provide an example. This can scare people looking for the answears. It would be nice if you edit your post since you fully answered the question but it is just unpleasant to read through.

Comment: The question is about C++, why do you use Rust in your examples?